# Django CRUD template not showing up

Tags: python, django

Im making a CRUD application using class instances.
My app is a very simple accounting app:

Django: 3.03
Python: 3.8.0

accounts/models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ## normal fields
```

accounts/views.py

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = '__all__'

class ProjectUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fields = '__all__'

class ProjectDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Project
    success_url = reverse_lazy('project')
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

path('project/create/', project_views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='project_create'),
    path('project/<int:pk>/update/', project_views.ProjectUpdate.as_view(), name='project_update'),
    path('project/<int:pk>/delete/', project_views.ProjectDelete.as_view(), name='project_delete'),

]
```

I have 2 template files under the following directory:

```
accounts
    accounts
        templates
            project
                project_form.html
                project_confirm_delete.html
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        forms.py
```

When i call the view:

http://localhost:8000/accounts/project/create/

I get the following error:

```
47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: accounts/project_form.html
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'accounts.utils.accounts_vars',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I cant figure out why this is not working. Can you please help.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It should be `/accounts/templates/accounts/project_form.html` Also check your settings https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration

Comment: the  template settings are:

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'account.utils.account_vars',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: Take a look at the first part of my comment.

Comment: Ivan, the actual folder layout is exactly as you suggested (it was my mistake that I didnt write the full folder path in my original post).

Comment: You did and your folder structure is not what I said. Under "templates" you have "project" - not "accounts".

Answer (score 0):

check your settings.py file

The views is not able to render your template. Mention templates directory in settings.py and also check wether your template is present or not

Comment: I have posted the template settings in the comment. I think im using the right template settings

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling your views which template to use. You do this by setting the template_name parameter in your view, e.g.:

```
class ProjectUpdate(UpdateView):  
      model = Project 
      fields = '__all__'
      template_name = 'project/project_form.html
```

'

Comment: I could do that. But then im hard coding the template files in the views. Isnt this wrong ?

Comment: It is at least the standard way as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/). The ```get_template_names``` method of the CBV has a specific algorithm for finding templates if the name is not provided. But your templates do not have the required name pattern (app_name/modelname_suffix.html) and I do not really see the advantage in your case of not passing the template_name.